# Counting all cliques of k vertices in a graph sequentially

Tags: algorithm, recursion, graph, social-networking, clique

Does exist a **sequential** algorithm for counting **all** k-cliques in an undirected graph?

With k-cliques I mean this: the number of sets of vertices that are all connected one another by edges in an undirected graph.

Here's where to find a more detailed description of a clique. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)

Comment: Have you read the [Wikipedia section about algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Cliques_of_fixed_size) for this problem?

Comment: Yea, I was looking for some pseudo code about it since I'm quite confused about it. I just have a recursive algorithm. @NicoSchertler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Bron–Kerbosch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm) to list all cliques in graph. Consider its siplest implementation (pseudocode from wikipedia):

```
BronKerbosch1(R, P, X):
    if P and X are both empty:
        report R as a maximal clique
    for each vertex v in P:
        BronKerbosch1(R ⋃ {v}, P ⋂ N(v), X ⋂ N(v))
        P := P \ {v}
        X := X ⋃ {v}
```

In each recursive call, the set `R` contains a clique, while iterating through all the cliques in the graph. Therefore you can alter the algorithm to print the clique whenever its size is `k` and cut the recursion, since any recursive call would only produce larger cliques.

```
BronKerbosch1(R, P, X, k):
    if |R| = k:
        report R as a k-clique
    else
        for each vertex v in P:
            BronKerbosch1(R ⋃ {v}, P ⋂ N(v), X ⋂ N(v))
            P := P \ {v}
            X := X ⋃ {v}
```

You can use the same idea when implementing optimized versions with pivoting and vertex ordering.

Comment: Thanks I'm going to try this approach. I'll accept this answer soon.